# php not getting key and value from generated url

Tags: php, mysql, forms, email

I am trying to create a forgot password and password reset module using PHP.

1. Users upon entering the email id, I am fetching the record from MySQL that matches with the email id. I am able to fetch the record.

   My reset_password form:

   ```
   <html>
     <body>
       <form method="post" action="sendlink.php">
         <p>Enter Email Address To Send Password Link</p>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <input type="submit" name="submit_email">
       </form>
     </body>
   </html>
   ```
2. I am creating a link with the email id and password and send it as a mail to the user.  I am able to send the email.  I am providing a part of the code that enables me to send the email with the link.

   ```
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit_email']) && $_POST['email'])
   {
     require 'connect.php';
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $select=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from users where email='$email'");
     if(mysqli_num_rows($select)==1)
     {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
       {
         $email=$row['email'];
         $pass=$row['pass'];
       }
       $link="<a href='www.mywebsite.com/reset_pass.php?key=".$email."&?reset=".$pass."'>Click to reset password.</a>";
       require_once "phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php";
       $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
       $mail->CharSet =  "utf-8";
   ```

   This is continued by other codes to send the mail.  This part is working correctly and I am receiving the mail.
3. When I click on the link received in the mail, I intend to open up a form to reset the password using reset_pass.php given in the link.

The following is the link that gets generated:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/reset_pass.php?key=user@theshoecompany.com&?reset=39eb0152f5a43c08169716dbf158f08e
```

Code to open the form to accept new password:

```
<?php
if($_GET['key'] && $_GET['reset'])
{
  $email=$_GET['key'];
  $pass=$_GET['reset'];
  require('connect.php');
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='$email' and pass='$pass'";
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);


//3.1.2 If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1)
  {
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="submit_new.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="emailnew" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
    <p>Enter New password</p>
    <input type="password" name='passwordnew'>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
  }
}
else {
  echo "<script>
                alert('could not get email or password');
                </script>";
}
?>
```

With the above code I wanted to open a form for the user to type in a new password.  But the values of email and password are not getting posted from the link.  The browser opens blank page, loads it and just remains blank without opening the form to accept the password.

How do i rectify this?

Comment: See this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: you probably should not be emailing password hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you've provided, the query string parameters are `key` and `?reset` because you have `?` twice in the generated reset_pass URL:

```
$link="<a href='www.mywebsite.com/reset_pass.php?key=".$email."&?reset=".$pass."'>Click to reset password.</a>";
                                                ^               ^
```

Based on your conditional in the `reset_pass.php` page, the page that loads should contain the `<script>alert(...)</script>` payload (because `'reset' != '?reset'`). If you "View Source" on the reset_pass.php page when it loads, you should see this as well - if you're not already seeing the alert.

If you update the link generation to contain only 1 `?`, it may work:

```
$link="<a href='www.mywebsite.com/reset_pass.php?key=".$email."&reset=".$pass."'>Click to reset password.</a>";
```

Comment: Many thanks @newfurniturey your solution worked...plus also I learnt something new.

Answer (score 3):

Your form's method is POST, you should get the values from `$_POST` instead of `$GET`.

The input value pairs will **NOT** be shown in URL but within HTTP request body if the method is POST.

Comment: I have tried using POST instead of GET....still the same issue...+ the url that gets generated does display the mail id and the encrypted password.

Comment: do you have other JS code hijacking the form post action?

Comment: not that I know of....In fact, its bizarre that this was working yesterday....I was trying to add some css to the form when everything came down....I did clean up the css forms too...

Comment: hey wait, where did `key` and `reset` come from? I don't see corresponding inputs in your form..

Comment: the key and the reset comes from the part 2 of my code...which generates this link `$link="<a href='www.mywebsite.com/reset_pass.php?key=".$email."&?reset=".$pass."'>Click to reset password.</a>"`....there is a select statement before this

Comment: Sorry didn't aware of the updated question. In your case there are only 3 possible causes for a blank page: 1) the first `IF` evaluates to false; 2) `$count` does not equal to 1; 3) There are PHP errors and the server settings suppressed the errors.

Comment: thank you for your support...yes...I figured the IF evaluates to false and check the php errors... thank you again.